# Create ODBC Data source within IIS

Tags: iis, odbc, dsn

Please can someone direct me where i go within IIS in order to create an ODBC DSN.

Tried numerous sites.  My old it manager set it up a while ago and i need to change some settings.

Comment: *ODBC Data Sources* in control panel, "System DSN" tab.

Comment: Hi Dan, i have already done this. The setting i am trying to set up is specifically within IIS. One of my collegues set it up a while back however has now left the business and cant remember exactly where it is.

Comment: The connection setup won't be within IIS, per se. It might be within one or more `ASP` and/or `ASP.NET` pages you're hosting/serving with IIS.